# Overriding a kernel module blacklisting that's reinstated during apt full-upgrade

Tags: apt, 18.04, kernel, lubuntu, udev

On an old laptop with Lubuntu 18.04, I have `sisfb` working properly. It's not blacklisted at all and loads on boot.

The problem is that `sisfb` is normally blacklisted in `/lib/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf`. While I can comment that line out, whenever the `udev` package is updated using the weekly GUI update reminder, `/lib/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf` is overwritten. While I can use `chattr +i /lib/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf` to block the update from overwriting the file, that causes `udev` updates to fail, which causes `apt full-upgrade` to fail. Since the laptop is for the use of someone new to computers, this isn't a workable method.

How can I load `sisfb` properly during boot?

Answer (score 2):

From ServerFault:

- [Automatically keep current version of config files when apt-get install](https://serverfault.com/questions/259226/automatically-keep-current-version-of-config-files-when-apt-get-install)

This answer:

```
apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes -y udev
```

Read the comments below the answer though. It suggests `--force-yes` is sometimes an extreme option although it's not explained clearly.

---

An even better ServerFault answer is found here:

- [Prevent update-manager from overwriting my Configs](https://serverfault.com/questions/557979/prevent-update-manager-from-overwriting-my-configs)

This Answer:

> You can pass options to dpkg from apt. Interesting for you would be
>   the option --force-confold. The command looks like this:
>
> ```
> apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
> ```
>
> Setting `--force-confdef` as well makes apt-get still update the
>   config file if it hasn't been edited, while `--force-confold` will
>   keep edited configuration files without asking.
>
> To make this permanent, you can also set these options in your
>   apt.conf file:
>
> ```
> Dpkg::Options {
>    "--force-confdef";
>    "--force-confold";
> }
> ```
>
> Check e.g.
>   http://debian-handbook.info/browse/wheezy/sect.package-meta-information.html#sidebar.questions-conffiles

Comment: Unfortunately, the `udev` package inscrutably doesn't consider that to be a configuration file (`dpkg --status udev`). I'll file a bug for that.

Comment: You would think anything ending in `.conf` should be respected as a configuration file and the industry standard rules should be followed. Perhaps a hook into shutdown / reboot scripts can run `diff` on current `.conf` file and saved copy. If different clobber the current file with saved good copy?

Comment: I've submitted [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1827753/). That's not a bad idea. I'll look into shutdown scripts for now and then use this answer if and when the bug is fixed. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround this by creating simple bash script and running it via cron or add it as systemd unit.

```
#!/bin/bash

SLEEP_TIME=30 # how often do the checks
BL="/lib/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf"

while [ true ]; do

    SISFB_BL=`grep "blacklist sisfb" $BL`

    if [[ "$SISFB_BL" ]]; then

        # sisfb un-blacklist
        sed -i '/blacklist sisfb/d' /lib/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf

    else

        echo "[ ok ] sisfb blacklist not found"

    fi

    sleep $SLEEP_TIME

done
```

save it i.e. as /opt/sisfb_blacklist_watcher.sh

and add to cron on root:

```
sudo -i
crontab -e
```

```
@reboot /opt/sisfb_blacklist_watcher.sh &> /dev/null &
```